# I'm trying to get a the string value of an element in a Javascript object to use in the value from another element

Tags: javascript, object

I'm building a website with some rpg stat blocks for a table top role playing game I'm trying get a string element to use data from another element. But it when I go to boot up a web browser it prints it as undefined.

These elements are part of the same object. I'm trying to assign a value to attarckroll. Then get it to display in actions.

```
    adaptiveShimmerer : {
        name: "Adaptive Shimmerer", 
        size: "Large",
        type: "Beast",
        subtype: "",
        alignment: "Unaligned",
        armorClass: "14 (Nautral Armor)",
        CalcHitPoints: 0,
        AutohitPoints: 66,
        hitDice: "6d10 + 30",
        hitDie: 10,
        hitDieNumber: 6,
        HP: function() {
            for(let i =0; i< this.hitDieNumber; i++)
            this.CalcHitPoints += ((1 + Math.floor(Math.random()*this.hitDie))+ (Math.floor(((this.con)-10)/2)))
        },
        Attack: function() {
            this.attackroll = ((this.proficiency + Math.floor(((this.str)-10)/2)).toString());
            console.log(this.attackroll)
        },
        speed: "20 ft, climb 20 ft.",
        proficiency: 2,
        str: 18,
        dex: 9,
        con: 20,
        int: 2,
        wis: 16,
        cha: 16,
        attackroll: "",
        savingThrows: "con: +7, cha: 5",
        skills: "",
        damageVulerabilites: "",
        damageResistance: "",
        damageImmunities: "",
        conditionImmunities:"",
        senses: "passive Perception 13",
        languges: "-",
        location: "Forest, Jungle",
        locationTags: {
            1: "Forest",
            2: "Jungle",
        },
        triome: "Indatha, Ketria, Zagoth",
        triomeTags : {
            1: "Indatha",
            2: "Ketria",
            3: "Zagoth"
        },
        cr: 2,
        xp: "(450 xp)",
        traits: "Shimmer. Any area within 60 feet of Adaptive Shimmerer counts as bright light. All creatures within 30 feet of Adaptive Shimmer (including itself) gain disadvantage on stealth checks. ",
        mutate: "Whenever this creature mutates, it gains +4 str and +4 con.",
        actions:"Bite. +" + this.attackroll +  " to hit, reach 5ft, one target. Hit: 16 (3d8 + 4 piercing damage).",
        legendaryActions: "",
        behaviour: "The Adaptive Shimmerer is usually the larval form of the Luminous Broodmoth, however due to Ikoria's unusual ecology it can mutate into almost any other Ikorian creature. Though quite large compared to humanoids it is quite shy, usually living in trees and eating absurd amounts of leaves. ",
        lair: "",
        imageUrl: "assets/adaptiveShimmerer.jpg",
        imageDiscription: "Giant Shiny Caturpiller",
```

I'm trying to paste it in HTML

```
    const html12=`
    <h3>Actions</h3>
    <p> ${monsterManual[item1].actions}</p><br>
    `
```

But when I do, the webpage only prints that it is undefined:
"Bite. +undefined to hit, reach 5ft, one target. Hit: 16 (3d8 + 4 piercing damage)."

Comment: Then don't put in in HTML right now, first do some console logging to find out whether it even has the value you need it to. And ask  yourself what `this` points to in the way you've defined `action` (it might also be a good time to define and then start using a class for this, instead of using bare objects).

Comment: You can't use `this` in the initialization of an object property. And even if you could, it wouldn't automatically update when `this.attackroll` changes. Anything that needs to use the dynamic state of the object needs to be a method, not a static value.